# How to use encrypt files for use with rsadecrypt?

Tags: openssl, rsa, terraform

I'm trying to use encrypted values in some Terraform code. I found some guides that indicated this order of operations:

```
# Generate key
openssl genrsa -out key.pem 8192 

# Encrypt
openssl rsautl -encrypt -inkey ./key.pem -in ./text.pub -out text.cypher

# Base 64 encode
openssl enc -a -in ./text.cypher -out ./text64.cypher -none

# Decrypt (in terraform)
rsadecrypt(filebase64("text64.cypher"), file("key.pem"))
```

However, this results in an error when run in `terraform console`:

```
> rsadecrypt(filebase64("text64.cypher"), file("key.pem"))

Error: Error in function call

  on <console-input> line 1:
  (source code not available)

Call to function "file" failed: no file exists at ../key.pem.
```

...which is really not helpful, and I'm not sure where to go from here. Is a prior step wrong? Is the usage wrong? No idea, and the library is deliberately not helpful.

Comment: Your output (`> rsadecrypt(filebase64("text64.cypher"), file("key.pem"))
` doesn't agree with your code nor the error message below it. And the error message seems unambiguous and perfectly clear. You are saying the private key is in a certain file and that file does not, in fact, exist.

Comment: This is just an error in transforming what I'm actually doing into the SO question. Ah, and I didn't grab the correct error response. I'll fix it in a bit, when I can.